How would you produce this type of scifi pattern using geo nodes?
I am looking for best way to fill face with lines that resemble scifi pattern.


Not sure if this is the best way ;-) but to me it looks like Shortest Edge Paths with some obstacles on the triangulated plane. By the way, don't you need any faces at all?

@Blunder the problem with "Shortest Edge Paths" is that the path doesn't remember its past while evaluating it, so you can't tell it to prefer to come back to it's original straight line. I think a repeat zone algorithm would give you much better control in this regard, but of course it would be slower. Also it would allow you to create paths that don't overlap, but here on reference we can actually see overlap.

@MarkusvonBroady Oh, I see. As soon as two "Shortest Edge Paths" meet, they will no longer separate for the rest of their way, as this is the shortest remaining path for both of them. The result looks more like a tree than the example. Or in other words, multiple start points take the same partial paths and end in fewer end positions.

@MarkusvonBroady Oh, you made it work. Great job! :)

Here's the Blunder's suggestion in the comment - Shortest Edge Paths + obstacles (the obstacles here is just removed geometry):


